# How can I contribute a keyboard layout (IPA) to ubuntu?

Tags: keyboard-layout, contributing

I have a launchpad account, but I've never contributed any code to Ubuntu before. I'd like to contribute an IPA keyboard layout, since it seems there isn't one already, and there should be. The easiest way I found to input IPA involves installing lots of third-party packages. If I make a new keyboard layout, I'd like for it to be available to the community, after some testing, of course.

Comment: BTW, have you seen that [someone has already created an IPA layout](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1387812&p=8740089#post8740089)?

Comment: I would rather use an input method instead of a keyboard layout. See this answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/113140/how-to-configure-keyboard-to-type-in-ipa-fonts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Maybe you could provide the layout via an own repo? See for example
   [Jawi  Keyboard layout and Font Project](https://launchpad.net/jawi)
   .
2. Another way would be to get it integrated in xkb. For this you had to [contact xorg developers](http://www.x.org/wiki/XorgMailingLists/).