# Streamline use of IPA notation in Libreoffice

Tags: libreoffice, special-characters

I use Character Map regularly alongside LibreOffice writer to write IPA (international phonetic alphabet) notation. All the (30ish) characters I need are in the 'Latin' script list, but there are **many** characters in this list that I do not need, and consequently it is a long process to find the characters I want, and making IPA notation is very time consuming. How can I streamline writing IPA notation in LibreOffice?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Found [this website](http://ipa.typeit.org/) which makes it easy to type IPA for many languages from anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To type in IPA, switch to an IPA keyboard layout.  It is much faster than hunting through the Character Map.  I use SIL's keyboard software, available for Windows, Mac and Linux.

For Ubuntu instructions, see [How to configure keyboard to type in IPA fonts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113140/how-to-configure-keyboard-to-type-in-ipa-fonts).

**Edit by OP**:

Here is how to set up IPA Keyboard for Ubuntu 16.04:

Download the SIL package as a .deb file from [packages.sil.org](http://packages.sil.org/) & install with GDebi or

```
sudo dpkg -i sil-repository.deb
sudo apt install ibus-kmfl
sudo apt install kmfl-keyboard-ipa
```

I got the right keyboard package by guessing the name, as I couldn't find a reference list anywhere on the SIL pages

Then in **Settings > Keyboard > Text Entry**

Under **Input Sources** click the <kbd>+</kbd> button to add a source and search for 'ipa', and it should come up. Click to add it.

Switch between input sources with <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> (this can be changed in Keyboard Settings)

You will need [this chart](http://www.tavultesoft.com/keyboarddownloads/%7BDF6682E6-9927-4896-BFED-254290003F85%7D/IPA%20Unicode%201.1%20Keyman%20Keyboard.pdf) to figure out how to actually enter the IPA characters!

Answer (score 0):

I think most solutions for entering IPA characters in LibreOffice will be the same as a solution for GUI applications in general, in which case any answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113140/how-to-configure-keyboard-to-type-in-ipa-fonts/981292#981292) should work here, including [mine](https://askubuntu.com/a/981292/469545), which uses the FCITX input method editor.